# Form and subform format problems

Tags: ms-access

I have a main form with only 1 field, in a combo box.  I have a subform linked to the main form on that field.  The logic is all working fine - when I select an item from the main form I get the correct results in the subform.

The problem I have is the appearance of the form.  I wanted both the form and sub form to be visible all the time.  Instead, I get only the main form, with a "+" next to each record.  Selecting the "+" then pops up the appropriately filtered subform.

I cannot find any menu selection s that are driving this format or allow me to change it to what I want.

Comment: Try to change the Form Properties -> Default View -> Continuous Forms. It seems as though you're viewing the data in Datasheet view, no?

Comment: I am using datasheet view.  I cannnot use continuous forms with a subform.  I also tried single form view - but then I cannot select a record from the combo box, because it thinks I'm trying to edit the current record instead of selecting a new record.  Maybe a search button - but that seems more awkward than I need.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=216600) out - it seems like this is your exact scenario. Is there a reason you "must" use Datasheet view?

Comment: That didn't do it - it describes how to use a single form, not a datasheet.  It seems I have to use datasheet view for the selection in the main form to work - unless I'm doing something else wrong there

Comment: I'm afraid how I'm confused on how only the Main Form is showing if it only has a combobox control on it.

Comment: Try -> Home ribbon, Records - More -> Subdatasheet -> Remove.

Comment: That option only allows for "expand all" or "collapse all", but the "remove" option is grayed out and not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the subdatasheet always expanded by default you can set the `Subdatasheet Expanded` (in the Format options) property to `yes`.

Comment: Well, that expands each of the items - but that's not what I need.  What I want is to see a subform that is always open, with just the records on the subform that match the selected record on the main form.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. You need a split form maybe. Can you change your default form view to Split Form and see if that looks like what you want?

Comment: @DonGeorge Was it the split form that did it for you?